# Starting a new line in bash scripting

Tags: bash, scripting

I need to start a new line after each field. I know I need to use `\n` at the end of the command how would I do it if I am using the cat command at the start.

I have tried using `&&` after the `awk -F : 'NR==1' && '\n'`. My code is:

```
cat /etc/shadow | awk -F : 'NR==1' && "\n"
cat /etc/shadow | awk -F : 'NR == 1 { print "Username: " $1, "\n"}'
```

Comment: The second one seems kinda okay to me, what's the problem with it?

Comment: @MuradZaman : The first variation doesn't make any sense. The `&& "\n"` is interpreted by bash, not awk, and `"\n"` is (hopefully) not a valid command on your system. If the question refers to the second line you posted, please add a _awk_  tag, because the question then refers more to awk than bash.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to split the fields in different lines, you can use

```
... | tr ':' '\n'
```

or when you want to hold the `:` at the end of each line

```
... | sed 's/:/:\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
&& echo or
&& Printf "\n"
```

Not clear the mean.

Comment: i need to get the first outcome,